# Django - Storing a users API session token securely

Tags: python, django, api, security, token

I have an application which issues a simple request with basic auth which returns a session token. I then want to use that token for subsequent calls to that same application interface.

My question is, is it OK to store this token in the session/cookie of the logged in user, or should I approach this a different way? I want to ensure 100% user security at all times.

Answer (score 2):

A session cookie is not a bad solution. You could also mark the cookie as "secure" to make sure that it only can be sent over https. It is far better than using i.e. localstorage.

Comment: In terms of of server security, should there be any steps I take when storing it in memory? Although, I presume it as to be stored in unencrypted.

Comment: You say that the token is sent from the client on every request. The application server will store it in memory when the request is processed. I don't believe you will gain much by encryping the token in memory. But you should probably take steps to avoid logging it to disk.